# Motion event has invalid pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16

Tags: android, authentication, fragment

I was following this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

And made a login and registration screen.

**The registration works propperly:**

[users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kBA6.png)

**But when I want to login it doesn't work:**

When i click the login button nothing shows up.

*Logcat:*

```
06-05 14:29:59.545 1723-1896/? E/InputDispatcher: Motion event has invalid   pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.
06-05 14:29:59.635 1723-1896/? E/InputDispatcher: Motion event has invalid   pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.
```

***Login:***

*Setup*

```
    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().finish();

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            // Check for empty data in the form
            if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {

                // login user
                checkLoginEmail(email, password);


            } else {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });



    }
```

*checkLoginEmail Method*

```
   private void checkLoginEmail(final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    // Now store the user in SQLite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user
                            .getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

*Extra*

```
    private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

*I made all that in a fragment.*

**SessionManager.java**

```
public class SessionManager {
// LogCat tag
private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();

// Shared Preferences
SharedPreferences pref;

Editor editor;
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Shared preferences file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHiveLogin";

private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN = "isLoggedIn";

public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void setLogin(boolean isLoggedIn) {

    editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, isLoggedIn);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();

    Log.d(TAG, "User login session modified!");
}

public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, false);
}
}
```